# What architecture of CNN to solving a image regression problem (case study: solving Poisson equation)?

Tags: computational-physics, poisson, machine-learning

I've been working on solving Poisson problem using CNN model (you can ignore the Poisson problem part if you not familiar and jump to the image processing/CNN part). More specifically, I am solving electric potential problem ($\phi$) by CNN algorithm with particle distribution ($\rho$) as the input in Cartesian coordinates, similar to [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16J3Xv9nZ5oKJQj4QnLvP8nHfeM9iaVzJ/view?usp=sharing) but with no permittivity.

The training input ($\rho$) is $20\times20$ pixels matrix and the data label ($\phi$) is also $20\times20$ matrix. Either input and label is a 5000 matrix (5000, 20, 20, 1). The input-label data set was obtained from Gauss-Seidel method.

The goal is to obtain electric potential ($\phi$) from input data particle distribution ($\rho$) with CNN model.

With this regression case, what is the best CNN architecture to use?